# add SceneKit Scene file to view controller

Tags: ios, scenekit

this is my first time adding the SceneKit into my app, 
I created a SceneKit file called "StarScene.scn" and I want to display it into my StarViewController, it does not work, I just don't know how to make it right. please help. Coding and screenshot below. Many thanks.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    SCNView *myView = (SCNView *)self.view;
    myView.scene = [SCNScene sceneNamed:@"StarScene.scn"];
    myView.allowsCameraControl = YES;
    myView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = YES;
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: from what I see on the Interface Builder screenshot, it seems that the `SCNView` is actually a subview of the controller's view, not the controller's view itself. Does your code crash? (that would confirm that `self.view` isn't a `SCNView` but a simple `UIView`).

Comment: oh yes, this is why, it works now. I didn't realise that the SCNView has to be directly under the controller view itself, thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what I see on the Interface Builder screenshot, it seems that the `SCNView` is actually a subview of the controller's view, not the controller's view itself. Does your code crash? (that would confirm that `self.view` isn't a `SCNView` but a simple `UIView`).

You will either want to have the `SCNView` as the controller's view, or create an `IBOutlet` so that you can retrieve and manipulate the SceneKit view from the view controller.

Answer (score 1):

i think a way is:

1. Add Scenekit **framework** in **build phases library**
2. Make a seprate class named **SCNView**
3. Configure your Scene and setup Nodes in method **-awakeFromNib {}**
4. Import **Scenekit/Scenekit.h** in your starViewController
5. In your storyboard check your **custom class** of your scene kit view that must be named that class you make in step 2
6. Now it's easy call your scenekit class by **allocating** and **init** method in starViewController
7. Enjoy Scenekit :)